# Определённая последовательность добавляемых элементов в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть, например, такой массив:
let arr_1 = [1, 2, 10, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4]

Есть второй массив:
let arr_2 = [2, 11, 7, 4, 8]

Суть задачи в том, что должно быть что-то вроде сравнения массивов, из arr_1 нужно найти и добавить дубликаты чисел в arr_2, при этом не нарушая последовательности элементов arr_2, и при этом не должно исчезнуть число, которого нет в arr_1, то есть число 11 должно остаться в массиве.

Результат должен быть: [2, 2, 11, 7, 4, 4, 4, 8]

Если честно, уже ума не приложу как это сделать. Хотелось бы это как-то провернуть с помощью циклов без методов, чтобы разобраться.

Несколько стыдно показывать свои тщетные попытки с помощью г-нокода, но все же я выложу:

```
let step = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr_1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr_2.length; j++) {
            if (arr_1[i] == arr_2[j]) {
                step[i] = arr_1[i]
            }
        }
    }

// Результат: [empty, 2, empty, 2, 8, empty × 2, 4, empty × 4, 7, 4]
```

Потом нужно было избавиться от пустых ячеек:

```
let ident = step.join(',').replace(/,/g, '').split('').map(Number)
```

Затем надо было как-то добавить 11, это я уже делал с помощью indexOf:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < arr_2.length; i++) {
        if (ident.indexOf(arr_2[i]) === -1) {
            ident.push(arr_2[i])
        }
    }

    // Получается такая фигня: [2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 7, 4, 11]
```

Меня не устраивает порядок. Как работает push я знаю, последний код я написал для того, чтобы вообще хоть как-то удалось добавить недостающий элемент. Под конец совсем запутался, как дальше поступить - ума не приложу, и вообще как это сделать, поскольку вышенаписанный код явно не подходит для этого.

Помогите плз. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: почему в результате две двойки, а не три?

Comment: @Grundy потому что в arr_1 две двойки. Сколько одинаковых чисел в исходном массиве, столько же должно быть и в результате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаём пустой массив, в который будем записывать числа в нужном порядке и в нужном количестве.
2. Так как порядок должен совпасть с порядком второго массива, будем следовать по второму массиву, попутно совершая поиск в первом массиве и добавляя найденные.
3. Если число в первом массиве отсутствует, то добавим это ненайденный элемент второго массива.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 10, 4, 2, 8, 9, 3, 4, 3, 6, 3, 6, 7, 4];
let arr2 = [2, 11, 7, 4, 8];

let len2 = arr2.length;
let res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
    let j = 0, isFound = false;
    let elem = arr2[i];
    while ((j = arr1.indexOf(elem, j)) != -1) {
        j++;
        isFound = true;
        res.push(elem);
    }
    if (!isFound) res.push(elem);
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!